# AdS/CFT and entropy

Tags: entropy, partition-function, ads-cft

I would like to calculate the [entropy of a CFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdS/CFT_correspondence) on a circle, and I know the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)) of the disk. Can I use AdS/CFT:

$$ Z_{CFT} = Z_{\text{bulk}}$$

To deduce :
$$S_{CFT} = (1-\beta \partial_\beta) \ln (Z_{CFT})= (1-\beta \partial_\beta) \ln (Z_{\text{bulk}})$$

Comment: you can use AdS/CFT of course. This was done by Lewkovicz and Maldacena

Comment: I couldn't find a reference for it, thanks a lot!!

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4926 I misspelled a name. Sorry